# handling time zone in a countdown plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have countdown plugin which takes a timestamp(in seconds) as an argument and returns a countdown to the given timestamp in form of day/houers/minutes .

all timestamps are calculated/stored in UTC timezone ... plugin used to work fine until i have changed my server and currently my server is in Newyork time zone .

as you can guess my countdown  plugin doens't work right anymore ...

here is the important part of the plugin

```
  // Time left
  time_left = Math.floor((options.timestamp - (new Date())) / 1000);
```

is there any way change time zone on fly like in php ? 
something like

```
 time_left = Math.floor((options.timestamp - (new Date('UTC'))) / 1000);
```

Comment: Take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for Date.UTC().  Use it like so:

```
var d = new Date();
Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds(), d.getUTCMilliseconds());
```